# IdentityServer4 custom token validation called only once

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am currently working on the logic of custom token validation. I need to deactivate the token when the user's password is changed (*change-password* endpoint is public).
I have implemented the `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` interface and resolved my class via DI
`.AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<TokenHashValidatorService>();`

However, I can see the following problem, my implementation of ICustomTokenRequestValidator only works when I generate a token and during only the first request to my API.
In logs I see the following information:

[JWKS request from log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2rWH.png)

During first request to API request to `/.well-known/openid-configuration` and `/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` is sent. But when I send a second, third, etc. requests my breakpoint in TokenHashValidatorService is skipped.

Is there any way I can forcefully initiate second `/.well-known/openid-configuration` and `/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` requests?
Or maybe I can somehow mark that "token validation needed" during the *change-password* flow?

I'm really stuck and out of options, I've read all the articles out there, any ideas?

Comment: _"I need to deactivate the token when the user's password is changed"_ - exactly which _token_ are you referring to? ...and you do know that synchronous token revocation is impossible, right?

Comment: Why would `GET /.well-known/openid-configuration` trigger token validation? The `openid-configuration` endpoint is not intended to be accessed by authenticated clients.

Comment: @Dai I referring **Access token**. I can't use token revocation for this case, because inside password-change service I don't have token, because password-change could be invoked without JWT token

Comment: @Dai, I just google a bit about jwks and found this info:
_The endpoint returns a JWKS containing public keys that enable clients to validate a JSON Web Token (JWT) issued by this OpenID Connect Provider._
So my assumption was that token validation happens during JWKS request

Comment: You're conflating token-**request**-validation (i.e. an IdP validating an OIDC token request), with _token-validation_ (i.e. an RP validating a token received from a client). They're separate concepts.

Comment: @Dai I did another trick. I just generate users with some TokenHash when I generate a token I add a token-hash claim to the token. When the password is changed I generate a new TokenHash and the last step is to add custom token validation where I will compare the token hash from a claim and token hash from ApplicationUser.
It works in general, but only for the first Request, the token key is cached or something like that, and my custom token validation is skipped.

Comment: @Dai, I also tried implement `ICustomTokenValidator` interface, but for some reason my validation never fires